# (A|B) testing Google Analytics, remove utm_expid from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

Im new to this and im trying to rewrite URL so that utm_expid is hidden so if my url is:

> http://www.myweb.com/?utm_expid=67183125-2

how would i make it so when user visits

> myweb.com

it does not show utm_expid in url

Is this possible using PHP/JS?

NOTE: i cant use RUBY or any other languages except PHP/JS/HTML

Comment: Why do you need to remove utm_expid?

Comment: i do not want to show utm_expid in the url

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to remove because GA's js is appending it to the url, so by rewriting the url without it, you could be breaking the code.  I wouldn't mess with it if it's purely for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: If you remove the utm_expid, the Content Experiment won't work. So, if you want to remove it, just turn off the experiment.

Comment: @Yahel I preen all my content experiments urls and work like a charm. I added and answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. Just redirect the page to base url once the `utm_expid=67183125-2` is got. ie,

```
if($_GET['utm_expid']) { //header to redirect to myweb.com }
```

Its a tricky way. Hope you are permitted to use it.

Just start a session and store value in session variable. you can regain it even page is re directed.

ie

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_GET['utm_expid']) {
$_SESSION['variable_name']=$_GET['utm_expid']
 //header to redirect to myweb.com 
}
?>
```

Comment: but wouldnt doing that loose the utm_expid value? or wouldnt it run into infinite redirect loop?

Comment: just start a session and store value in session variable. you can regain it even page is re directed... i edited answer.

Comment: This trick will lost some data relative to the user conduct like the time is spending surfing your site or the data of each funnel's stage. I added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add this Javascript trick that is server agnostic.

```
if (location.search.indexOf('utm_expid') > -1) {
  history.replaceState('page', 'Title', '/')
}
```

I recommend you to place it at the end of the `body`.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted a clean URL (as you do for branding and manual sharing purposes), I'd script it so that you load a full page iFrame which loads the gA test queried URL. That way the user see s the clean URL in the address bar and still see the experiment.

You could use PHP to set up your index page (or any server side, or even client side script).

Comment: This is wrong in so many levels, but specially on that idea of load an iframe. Just replace the history state with the root ones. I added an answer with more details.

Comment: Not technically wrong. It would work fine. It's not an ideal solution, and has usability and accessibility issues, but it is still a solution. iFrames have much better browser support than API access to the history state.